# Input not stored in local storage

Tags: javascript, dom, input, local-storage

I'm having a problem to store the input from a textbox in to local storage, all I get is 'undefined. I seem to have followed allt tutorials for local storage but still it doesn't work. I have an index.html, app.js and name.js. The function in name.js should store the input on the click-event taking place in app.js. Where am I going wrong?

index.html:

```
<form id="nameForm">
  <label>Ditt namn (Max 10 tecken):
    <input type="text" id="name" maxlength="10" />
  </label>
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="Choose" />
</form>
```

name.js: (and it says that localStorage is not defined)

```
function name () {
  let nickname = document.querySelector('#name')
  localStorage.Nickname = nickname.value
  console.log(nickname)
}

module.exports = name
```

app.js:

```
const timer = require('./timer.js')
const Quiz = require('./Quiz.js')
const name = require('./name.js')

let start = document.querySelector('#submit')
function quizAndTimer () {
  Quiz()
  timer()
  name()
}
start.onclick = quizAndTimer
```

Comment: Where do you use your name.js-File? It seems to be Node code, but the localStorage object is meant to be used in the browser.

Comment: @LucaKiebel I use it in a module name name.js which I exports and imports into app.js which is the called upon in index.html. Does that answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
localStorage.setItem('Nickname', nickname.value); // this stores 

localStorage.getItem('Nickname') // this retrieves
```

Comment: No, still undefined after that change.

Comment: I can see it working fine in the fiddle and I thank you for that. But even if I copy your code into mine I still get undefined. Could this be to the fact I'm using a localhost:4000 for my page?

Comment: But when I used getElementById instead of querySelector I got the result...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
localStorage.Nickname = nickname.value;
```

Use:

```
localStorage.setItem('NickName', nickname.value); //this sets your key/value pair in localStorage.
```

> P.S.: localStorage saves only in the format key/value pairs and both (key and value)
>   are always in the string format.